# StructureMap Open Generic Types

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IRenderer<T> 
{
    string Render(T obj);
}

public class Generic<T> { }

public class SampleGenericRenderer<T> : IRenderer<Generic<T>>
{
    public string Render(Generic<T> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call StructureMap with 
`ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRenderer<Generic<string>>>();` and receive `SampleGenericRenderer<string>`.

I'm currently using the following registration and receiving this error when I call GetInstance. "Unable to cast object of type:

> ConsoleApplication1.SampleGenericRenderer'1[ConsoleApplication1.Generic'1[System.String]]'
>   to type
>   'ConsoleApplication1.IRenderer'1[ConsoleApplication1.Generic'1[System.String]].

```
public class CoreRegistry : Registry
{
    public CoreRegistry()
    {
        Scan(assemblyScanner =>
        {
            assemblyScanner
                .AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IRenderer<>));
            assemblyScanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IRenderer<>));
            assemblyScanner
                .ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(
                    typeof(IRenderer<>));
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to configure StructureMap so that it creates `SampleGenericRenderer<string>` instead of `SampleGenericRenderer<Generic<string>>`?

UPDATE: I ended up doing the type construction myself for this subset of dependencies. Because they combine contextual binding with a lot of unsupported generic bindings, this turned out to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe StructureMap has any mechanism for closing an *inner* generic parameter like this.

It's not ideal, but you might try creating your own `IRegistrationConvention` and whenever encountering a type that is a closed type of `Generic<>`, do the following:

```
var generic_t = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var sample_renderer_t = typeof(SampleGenericRenderer<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var renderer_t = typeof(IRenderer<>).MakeGenericType(generic_t);
graph.AddType(renderer_t, sample_renderer_t);
```

See http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section11 for more details.

Comment: This is definitely the road I was going down, and I think it will work. There's quite a bit of scanning involved to make it work in the actual codebase because I have to find all of the possible generic parameters and I don't know anything about the renderers or rendered types at compile time, but it ends up making the rest of the code much cleaner. As a note, ITypeScanner was replaced by IRegistrationConvention in a recent version of StructureMap. The documentation is a bit out of date!

Comment: @ShaneFulmer I forgot about that rename. Indeed, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As Pete explained, there is probably no way with StructureMap to do this. Other DI containers might yield more success, but not all contains have great support for more complex generic trickery. The only one I know for sure that allows you to do this is the [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org). With the Simple Injector, you just need the following configuration:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.Register(typeof(IRenderer<>), typeof(SampleGenericRenderer<>));

// Usage
var renderer = container.GetInstance<IRenderer<Generic<string>>>();

renderer.Render(new Generic<string>());
```

More info about this method can be found [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#registration-of-open-generic-types).

Comment: With the complexity of the generics I'm trying to use this pattern with, I think I need some of the additional extension points that Simple Injector adds. I'm running into too many limitations with StructureMap so I'm going to give Simple Injector a try!

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x=>x.AddRegistry<CoreRegistry>());

        var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(IRenderer<string>)) as IRenderer<Generic<string>>;

        var render = instance.Render(new Generic<string>());

    }
}
```

This throws an exception:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRenderer<Generic<string>>>();
```

What is your real problem?

EDIT:

Under some circumstances this could work too (If you don't know `Generic<string>` at design time):

```
static void Main()
{
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<CoreRegistry>());

    var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(IRenderer<string>));
    var methodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Render");
    methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new[] { new Generic<string>() });
}
```

Comment: Well I guess the issue with that example is that I don't know anything about SampleGenericRenderer from the client code, so I can't cast to it. All I know from the client is that I have a Generic<string> and I need a class that will handle its rendering.

Comment: No I wouldn't consider it a DTO in the real example. I think the changed code would return the wrong renderer if I'm not missing something. In the actual code, there would also be an IRenderer<string> in addition to the IRenderer<Generic<string>>.